# Excel VBA - copy several cells from the same row as activecell, then paste them to the first blank row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA, so I don't have much of a clue where to start here.

Basically, I have a front sheet that's a waiting list and ten staff sheets to track active clients; the waiting list has ten buttons to send data to each sheet respectively.
In the waiting list, I'd like to be able to click any cell in a given row to select it, then click one of the buttons, which will then copy the contents of columns A:G in that row, into the first blank row in the respective sheet.

So, for example, I click cell C6 in the waiting list, then click the button for staff sheet 1: cells A6:G6 will be copied and pasted into the staff sheet cells A15:G15, which is the first blank row in staff sheet 1.

I don't need it to delete anything from the waiting list, everything else is set up to work perfectly; I just need the vba code to do exactly as in the example.

Hope that's clear - any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit - Apologies, I didn't mean for this question to come across as expecting a code for me service. I've looked for existing answers to this for a few days, tried quite a few things, but it's all been abortive - I worried that posting the code that I've tried would just confuse things further. The most substantive solution I found had a few errors but otherwise looked sensible, but I got rid of it when it didn't work and can't track it down again. I'll post it if I find.

Thanks anyway

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help). As an aside, you can do this with just one button assuming the staff is in a column on the master sheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a code for me service.  There are many tutorials that already exist on how to code in vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I settled on, for anyone interested:

```
Sub CopytoSheet2()


Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":M" & ActiveCell.Row)

If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Value) = True Then
Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count). _
    Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
Else
Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count). _
    Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
End If

End Sub
```

There are ten buttons in the sheet, one each to send to a different member of staff. The Waiting List is named Sheet1 in the VBA properties, so the first staff sheet is Sheet2, etc.  There's a separate Sub for each button.

The user clicks on a cell in the row they want to copy, then clicks the button, and it copies the values of columns A:M of that row into the first blank row in the respective sheet.